# Recover/Decode encoded php code

Tags: php, encryption, decode, encode

we had an ex employee handling our servers and he left due to some issues. now he encoded all the php files on the server and we are struggling to get it back.
can any one help in decoding the file or maybe let us know which encryption is it and how to recover codes.

We tried using many online decoders and other stack over flow suggested techniques but ended up with a  buggy code.

I have pasted a sample code on https://pastebin.com/4uwZLZVF

A sample first line

```
<?php {"G\x4cOB\x41L\x53"}["gb\x73\x73\x69\x62"]="t\x65\x63hid";${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x66\x65ll\x77\x68j\x6c"]="co\x6et\x5f\x72e\x73\x32";
```

Comment: Here you go [https://pastebin.com/AAqPTm7e](https://pastebin.com/AAqPTm7e), but be careful. As mentioned in Ilmari Karonen's answer the code might contain malware.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by decoding the `\xNN` [escape sequences](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in the string literals, which should at least give you some idea of what the code is doing.  For example, the first line becomes:

```
<?php {"GLOBALS"}["gbssib"]="techid";${"GLOBALS"}["fellwhjl"]="cont_res2";
```

(And no, I have no idea why the first `{"GLOBALS"}` has no `$` before it. Looks like a syntax error to me.)

Anyway, if the ex-employee didn't originally write that code, you'd probably be best off restoring it from backups. (You do have backups, right?) Treat anything they did write as untrustworthy —given that they were willing to sabotage their employer to this extent, who knows what kind of other traps they may have buried in the code.  Even if you manage to deobfuscate it, unless you're willing to carefully inspect every line of the code (which probably takes as much work as just reimplementing it) you can't be sure it doesn't contain some malware that compromises your server.

Oh, and call your lawyer.  Given this kind of deliberate sabotage, there's got to be something you can sue your ex-employee for — probably breach of contract, at least.  Assuming you can still track them down, that is.  But you might, since they presumably had some motive for doing this to you (e.g. to extort extra money from you for the unobfuscated code), and unless it's pure revenge, they can't get what they want if they just walk away without any trace.

(Of course, that's assuming you didn't breach the contract you had with them first.  If the reason they left you with obfuscated code is because you promised to pay them and didn't, then you probably won't have much luck with suing them, and should either pay up or give up.  Consulting a lawyer might still be worthwhile, if you're not sure if you're in the right or not.  If you do decide to pay the ex-employee for the unobfuscated code, you might still want to treat it as suspect — although, if it turns out that it still doesn't do what you want after you've fully paid for it, you're at least in a much stronger position legally.  Oh, and if you didn't have a written contract before, make sure to insist on one now before paying anything.  And have your lawyer read it before you sign it.)